# Unit test for MongoTemplate updateFirst() method in Junit

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, junit

How to write unit test (via Junit) for MongoTemplate updateFirst() method ?

I have this service class:

```
    @Service
public class TemplateServiceImpl implements TemplateService
{
    @Resource
    private TemplateRepository templateRepository;

    @Resource
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public TemplateDto create(TemplateDto templateDto)
    {
        TemplateDto result;
        templateDto.setDeleted(false);
        result = templateRepository.insert(templateDto);
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean update(ObjectId id, TemplateDto templateDto)
    {
        if (templateDto != null)
        {
            Update update = new Update();

            if (templateDto.getName() != null)
            {
                update.set("name", templateDto.getName());
            }
            if (templateDto.getTemplate() != null)
            {
                update.set("template", templateDto.getTemplate());
            }
            if (templateDto.isDeleted())
            {
                update.set("deleted", Boolean.TRUE);
            }
            update.set("lastUpdate", new Date());
            return mongoTemplate.updateFirst(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(id)), update, "template")
                    .wasAcknowledged();
        }
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

I want write unit test for update method .
This is my relevant test class:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class TemplateServiceImplTest
{

    @InjectMocks
    private static TemplateServiceImpl templateService;

    @Mock
    private static TemplateRepository templateRepository;
    @Mock
    private static MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    private static TemplateDto templateDto;
    private static List<TemplateDto> listOfTemplates;
    private static String requestBody;


    @BeforeAll
    private static void setUp(){
        templateDto = createTemplateDto();
        listOfTemplates = createListOfTemplate();
        requestBody = createRequesyBody();
    }


    @Test
    void create()
    {
        when(templateRepository.insert(templateDto)).thenReturn(templateDto);
        TemplateDto actualResult = templateService.create(TemplateServiceImplTest.templateDto);
        assertThat(actualResult).isNotNull();
        assertThat(actualResult).isInstanceOf(TemplateDto.class);
        assertThat(actualResult.getId()).isEqualTo(templateDto.getId());
    }


    @Test
    void update()
    {
        Update update = new Update();
/*
        when(mongoTemplate.updateFirst(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(templateDto.getId().toString())) ,update , TemplateDto.class)).thenReturn(
                UpdateResult.acknowledged());
*/

/*
        given(mongoTemplate.updateFirst(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(templateDto.getId().toString())) ,update , TemplateDto.class));
*/

        boolean actualResult = templateService.update(templateDto.getId(), templateDto);
        assertThat(actualResult).isNotNull();
        assertThat(actualResult).isTrue();
    }
// other methods...
}
```

I mocked MongoTemplate like this:

```
@Mock
private static MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

when I run test I get NPE for mongoTemplate at update method , I searched and I saw this 2 approach:

```
            when(mongoTemplate.updateFirst(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(templateDto.getId().toString())) ,update , TemplateDto.class)).thenReturn(
                UpdateResult.acknowledged());
// Or

        given(mongoTemplate.updateFirst(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(templateDto.getId().toString())) ,update , TemplateDto.class));
```

But None of them worked! .
Thank you all .

Comment: Sounds like the mock `MongoTemplate` is not being injected into the class under test.  Does the code use constructor injection or @Value injection?  Please update the question with the rest of the test class and the class under test.

Comment: @AndrewS i edited my post . please check it again .tnx

Comment: Since it's being injected with `@Resource` you'll need `@ExtendWith` with spring so that the dependency is actually injected. (Or create a constructor to avoid the unit test from having to create a spring context.)